# How to get the handle of an anonymous module with requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

```
define(['somethingRequired'],function(somethingRequired) {
   // code
});
```

let's say this code is inside test.js , using the console, how could I inspect it and fiddle with its properties after it has been loaded? From the documentation I've seen that modules can be given names but that's not the case, I am wondering what happens to anonymous modules. Sorry in advance if the question is unclear or poorly written, accepting feedbacks

Update for Louis answer: I tried both the short form
    //var foo = require(['foo']);
     var foo = require('foo');
and the asynchronous call
    require(['foo'], function (foo_) { foo = foo_; });
Neither made the module leak in global scope. Am I still missing something?
Also tried to add a console.log('done') in the asynchronous call but it never showed up in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood what it means to call `define` without a module name as the first parameter. The only thing it does is let RequireJS figure out the module name at run time on the basis RequireJS's configuration. For instance, let's suppose I have a file which from the `baseUrl` directory would have the relative path `foo/bar.js` and this file calls `define` without setting a module name. I could load this module by doing `require(['foo/bar'], ...` However, if I have the following configuration:

```
paths: {
    bar: 'foo/bar'
}
```

Then I could load it with `require(['bar'], ...` If I had a `define` in the file that also *sets* the module name, either one of two methods of loading the module would certainly fail. If I have `define('foo/bar', ...` then the first `require` would work but not the second. If I have `define('bar', ...` then the second `require` would work but not the first.

Ultimately, though, when you load a module that does not call `define` with a module name, **you still have to load it using some name.** So you need to figure out what name the application you are examining uses to refer to the module that interests you, and use that name.

The only things you can fiddle with once a module is loaded are the values that your module export. Anything not exported is off-limits.

Once you've got a name for your module, you have to issue a `require` call at the console to get a reference to the module. If the module is already loaded, you can use `var foo = require(module_name)`. This is the synchronous form of `require` which is convenient to use but works only if a module is already loaded. If the module is not already loaded, then you have to use something like `require([module_name], function (foo_) { foo = foo_ });` (note how the first parameter is an array here) to get a global `foo` to be set to your module. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31182320/1906307) for a more verbose expalanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of self invoking functions inside the module so that it is executed as soon as the module is loaded.

More about self invoking functions - 
[A self invoking anonymous function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203897/a-self-invoking-anonymous-function-expression)

Comment: I am trying to understand others code that's using requirejs